# Pinescript Multi Asset Level Screener

Tags: pine-script

I wanted to build a support and resistance indicator which screens a list of pairs for example ['AUDCAD', 'CHFJPY', 'EURUSD'] and gets the support and resistance values for these, once we have those values. I want to trigger an alert whenever the price is close to approaching the support and resistance price(I'll provide more tangible conditions of course)

I have an indicator that plots support and resistance lines for the pair, just a simple high-low line for now but Ill polish it as I go on.

I wanted to understand if I could build a multi-asset level screener that triggers alerts for those pairs when the condition is reached.

If you can provide me general guidelines on how to do this, it would be great.

I want to build this using pinescript. If it is not possible then I would want to look into other options like python etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty easy to do. Instead of thinking of "support" and "resistance" as lines, though, consider them as prices, since that is what they are.

With that in mind, you will need your support and resistance prices to be defined, and will need a threshold price difference for when you should be alerted. Something like this would work, but may need to be modified for your exact idea:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Support/Resistance", overlay=true)

var float myLinePrice = 50.00  // support or resistance
var float threshold = 2.00 // how close you want the price to be before being notified
float distance = math.abs(close - myLinePrice)
bool alertCondition = distance <= threshold
hline(myLinePrice, "My Line", color=color.red) // i added this for intuition
```

Then you can set an alert for this script and tie it to the pair that you're interested in.

Similarly, though, you can do most of this by clicking through the "Alerts" buttons and setting an alert there; pinescript isn't necessarily needed for what you're asking. You could imagine your support/resistance, then consider your threshold value at which you want to be alerted, and set that as your alert crossing price.

EDIT:

You asked for a method to put multiple pairs into the same script. You can do this, but it complicates things, and unless you're trying to cut down on how many scripts you're running (I assume that's why you need it), I'd recommend putting the same script on different pairs for clarity and efficiency in managing the script.

Anyways, consider the `security` function used here:

```
//@version=5
indicator("get other prices", overlay=true)

getCurrencyPairPrice(pair) =>
   request.security(pair, timeframe.period, close)

float chfjpyPrice = getCurrencyPairPrice("FX:CHFJPY")
float eurusdPrice = getCurrencyPairPrice("FX:EURUSD")
```

This allows you to gather the prices of different pairs on your chart. It visually won't make much sense if you try to plot it, since it could be orders of magnitude off the values of the current pair on the chart, but the value can be used.

Pick your support and resistance for each indicator, apply it to what we made in the first part of this question, pull in the value of the pair using the function above, and create your alert.

Again, this is far more complicated and difficult to manage than using 5 lines of code on each pair individually, but will save you in total scripts used.

Comment: This is quite interesting, I shall proceed with this approach.. But can I do this for multiple pairs with a single script?

Comment: @samsupertaco Please note that begging for upvotes/accepts is frowned upon on SO.

Comment: This is what I wanted to know about. Helps a ton, Thanks!